# I can't get in the door at the shrine of winter

Tags: dark-souls-2

I have killed all the four main bosses and lit all the primal bonfires and used them. I have over 2 million soul memory and 250,000+ in hand. I however only have two of the great souls on hand as I used the others to trade for weapons but it still stays closed. Do I need all great souls in hand? What am I missing? Please help

Comment: Mhhh... could be you actually missed the great soul after the douk's dear freja fight. You don't automatically get it. It's a glowing orb near the dragon head.

Comment: Yeah I got it. I just don't get it. I've done everything I can think of and even everything I've read so far...

Comment: Are you at the right door? If it says "produce the symbol of the king" it's the wrong door.

Comment: I've gone do far as even using bonfire aesthetics to get the old iron king soul and the list sinner soul. See if I get all the great souls again and keep them in hand to see if that helps. I don't have anymore aesthetics though and can't find anymore. I was dumb and sold them all earlier in the game as I didn't really know what they were for.

Comment: No it's the right door. Through the shrine of winter and every time I go up to it says closed

Comment: Then I'm out of ideas, sorry.

Comment: The condition are: get all 4 souls of the bosses. As 5pike said, go check again by freja you might have missed it ( happened to me as well ). Other than that, I'm out of ideas as well.

Comment: Oh, you should also have at least 1 milions soul memory per ng, 1 milion soul memory for first playthrough, 2 milions if you are in ng+, ... How much soul memory do you have?

Comment: Soul memory is almost 2.5 million. And 250,000 in hand. I don't have all the souls anymore just 2 the other two I traded for weapons. Do I need them on hand? And yes I got the orb from freja. And first playthrough

Answer (score 3):

To open the Shrine of Winter, you can do one of two things:

1. Kill all of the "Primal" bosses, *and* activate the Primal bonfires. These are:

   - The Rotten
   - The Lost Sinner
   - The Old Iron King
   - The Duke's Dear Freja

**Note:** Freja's Soul is easily missed, as it is not automatically picked up. To pick it up, you will need to activate the red orb at the back of the arena. Additionally, the Bonfire is also easily missed. The room contains two enemies that must be defeated before the bonfire can be lit.

2. Get enough Soul Memory. The rule is to get 1,000,000 Soul Memory per NG.

The [Wiki page](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Shrine+of+Winter) describes all of this in greater detail.

As per the comments, you mentioned that you had indeed met all of these parameters, but we're still unable to enter. The only other solution I might suggest is (depending on the platform) reinstall it (for PC), or attempt to try and replicate the error again with another character.